# how to insert multiple values of an attribute into mongoDB using java with Map?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am writing a java code to insert form values into mongoDB using java code. I am using map to retrieve all the values from the map and inserting it into mongoDB. However, if an attribute is having multiple values, it is only inserting only one value. My code is:

```
Map<String, String[]> articleData =  request.getParameterMap();
for(String key : articleData.keySet())
{
    for(int i=0; i<articleData.get(key).length;i++)
{

 document.put(key,articleData.get(key)[i]);
 }
 }
table.insert(document);
```

However, right now, it is overriding the values of the attribute having multiple values.
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It will give you a basic idea. Adjust code according to your program:

```
Map<String, String[]> articleData =  request.getParameterMap();
for(String key : articleData.keySet())
{
    BasicDBObject data =new BasicDBObject();
    for(int i=0; i<articleData.get(key).length;i++)
       {
         data.put("",articleData.get(key)[i]);

       }
     document.put(key,data);
 }
table.insert(document);
```

Comment: Thanks Umair. It worked. But is there any way I don't have to use this for loop and not to create another DBObject?

Comment: Try this: Maybe it works but I am not sure

`Map<String, String[]> articleData =  request.getParameterMap();
    for(String key : articleData.keySet())    {
        
         document.put(key,articleData.get(key));
     }
    table.insert(document);`

Comment: I tried this but it overrides the previous value for the attribute and only retains the last values.

Comment: I removed the inner for loop in the last comment. Have you tried that? replace this line `document.put(key,articleData.get(key));` with `document.put(key,(BasicDBObject)articleData.get(key));` Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Encode a JSON object .
Try this out.

```
Map<String, String[]> articleData =  request.getParameterMap();
for(String key : articleData.keySet())
{

            JSONObject out = new JSONObject();
            out.put("key", key);
            out.put("value", articleData.get(key));
            System.out.println(out);

 }
 dbobj.put("multiple",out);
collection.insert(dbobj);
```